# Can't seem to uppercase the first letter in each word

Tags: javascript, function, loops, nested-loops

Write a function `snakeToCamel(str)` that takes in a snake_cased string and returns
the string CamelCased. snake_case is a string where each word is separated with
underscores (_). CamelCase is a string where the first char of each word
is capitalized, all other characters lowercase.

Examples:

```
snakeToCamel('snakes_go_hiss'); // => 'SnakesGoHiss'
snakeToCamel('say_hello_world'); // => 'SayHelloWorld'
snakeToCamel('bootcamp_prep_is_cool'); // => 'BootcampPrepIsCool'
snakeToCamel('BOOtcamp_PREP_iS_cOol'); // => 'BootcampPrepIsCool'

function snakeToCamel(str) {
    var newString = '';
    var words = str.split('_');

    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (j === 0) {
                newString += words[i][j].toUpperCase();
            } else {
                newString += words[i][j].toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript method for changing snake\_case to PascalCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082153/javascript-method-for-changing-snake-case-to-pascalcase)

Comment: looks like homework, however code looks reasonable.

Comment: I agree with @Loopo in that this looks like homework, and I think it would be good if @aperri where to ask a specific question as to where they're having issues or getting stuck... Suggestion one, the _`for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {...}`_ and other loop probably should be _`for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {...}`_, to avoid assigning globally scoped `i` and `j`. Suggestion two, `words` likely should be `const` not `var` assigned.

Comment: One more thing @aperri, I think ya may want to look into how to convert [a string into a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33233956/2632107), there are a few ways but the linked to one likely will be the most concise for correcting one of your loops ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have your second loop iterate over the length of the word not the length of the words array.

```js
function snakeToCamel(str) {
  var newString = '';
  var words = str.split('_');

  for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++) { // <--- the ith word's length
      if (j === 0) {
        newString += words[i][j].toUpperCase();
      } else {
        newString += words[i][j].toLowerCase();
      }
    }

  }
  return newString;
}
console.log(snakeToCamel('snakes_go_hiss'));
console.log(snakeToCamel('say_hello_world'));
console.log(snakeToCamel('bootcamp_prep_is_cool'));
console.log(snakeToCamel('BOOtcamp_PREP_iS_cOol'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Function for converting snake_cased to camelCased

Use the map function for converting first letter of each words to uppercase then join each words

```
function snakeToCamel(str){
    newString=""
    var words=str.split(_)
    var uppercasedWords=words.map(word=>{
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase+word.slice(1);
    })
    for(i=0;i<=uppercasedWords.length;i++){
        newString+=uppercasedWords[i]
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to PascalCase (the first letter is Uppercase), refer to this:

[Javascript method for changing snake_case to PascalCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082153/javascript-method-for-changing-snake-case-to-pascalcase)

If you want to convert to camelCase (the first letter is lowercase),  refer to this:

https://catalin.me/javascript-snake-to-camel/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution.

Define a function that converts a word to be first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase (I called it title as that's what its called in [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)). Then split the string, map the words and rejoin it.

```
function title(s){
    if(s.length == 0) return s;

    return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

function snakeToCamel(str) {
    return str.split('_').map(title).join('');
}

[
    'snakes_go_hiss',
    'say_hello_world',
    'bootcamp_prep_is_cool',
    'BOOtcamp_PREP_iS_cOol'
].map(snakeToCamel).forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Output:

```
SnakesGoHiss
SayHelloWorld
BootcampPrepIsCool
BootcampPrepIsCool
```