# Is it possible to use json parse to change the keys from underscore to camelCase deep nested?

Tags: javascript

I have object in json string:

```
const str = `[{"user_id":"561904e8-6e45-5012-a9d8-e2ff8761acf6","email_addr":"jilov@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]},{"user_id":"5904003b-452b-535c-9615-94706bf6c66c","email_addr":"sawu@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]}]`;
```

I want to parse this string (JSON.parse), but I also want to convert every underscore key to camelCase (in all levels).

Is it possible to use parse and convert in the same function? or I need to do it in separate steps?

Comment: You could use the`reviver` function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I see I can change the value, not see how to change the key..

Comment: May you share an attempt using the `reviver` parameter?

Comment: Not sure how because in the reviver the function is expect value.

Answer (score 1):

Because you asked in the comment how to do that with `reviver`, here a solution using that method.

But I'm not sure if I should consider that one as a good solution.

It relies on how the traversing for the reviving pass is done and according to [25.5.1 JSON.parse ( text [ , reviver ] )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-json.parse) and [25.5.1.1 InternalizeJSONProperty ( holder, name, reviver )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-internalizejsonproperty) it should always work.

But I personally wouldn't rely on that (because reviver wasn't intended for that usage) and instead, reimplement the traversing.

`this` in the `reviver` callback refers to the container to which `key` and `value` belong.

```js
const str = `[{"user_id":"561904e8-6e45-5012-a9d8-e2ff8761acf6","email_addr":"jilov@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]},{"user_id":"5904003b-452b-535c-9615-94706bf6c66c","email_addr":"sawu@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]}]`

const snakeToCamel = str => str.replace(/([-_]\w)/g, g => g[1].toUpperCase());

var parsed = JSON.parse(str, function(key, value) {
  const camelCaseKey = snakeToCamel(key)
 
  if (this instanceof Array || camelCaseKey === key) {
    // if this is Array 
    // or key does not change after converted to camel case
    // then just return the value so that the default "reviving" is done
    return value
  } else {
    // if key changes assing value to camel case one and return nothing
    this[camelCaseKey] = value
  }
});

console.dir(parsed)
```

[source of `snakeToPascal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57834750/1960455)

Comment: That's fun, I've tried this solution earlier in the TS playground and it doesn't seem to work... Works on JSFiddle though. Maybe this unintended use case isn't supported in some versions, I don't know...

Comment: @a2br the code works fine for me on TS playground in Firefox and Chromium-based browsers. In addition to that TS playground is for typescript, so if it does not work there but here and on JSFiddle then the problem is likely to be the TS-Compiler or the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a playground that solves that problem. You can check it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOMC8MAGBtA3gIgK4QFN4B9ASwBNsAubAVgDYBGATgAYAWAgDgFp6D2tHrVaMATDwCGzcrwJiAZgq4B2JpOAL62ADTYCAW0mkANsUnly8atgBWpkADcAAgskBrAgDpQB3dnICKGMTCGosbGBSKABPYjBJAwIbN08YKNj-UFwwKHg4hKSUjwJ0kBy8mOwAXwBdap0cfCIyShpaNnZWVgBmACMeQTEB2h7aYB5mJiFmdhVWej6tYHp6YH9DEPNLaxoISQB3XFcSnxA-PUDg0zCqCIyCxOSaVNKHrPLc-Pin4rTsr5VOp1VAAbgAUKBILA8gRSigAFIAZQA8gA5LwAB0k8EIAAoEABKCHghQ5YBQUjgGBQEAAYSeJgZ%20IgCU8xGAkkIVDgeVIYAA5oSeQh%20QKYJhwTBpTB4EFcPAwHA2QQOVzvHLMSYNAQ8QB6PHoHjEWroSQ8ABetUJetIAp0MDxABJGITkAA%20CVSmU%20uVQBVKl1eWkAVUxmKIzN1hO9PrjMC8mu1wF1AHIeKmHanUzH4-HEwQtTq8aniJmYNnibGYNUq9VwaTyZTqXlJJAFCB4AYUX1bAQKXiQL2eTl3GAQAcwMKYKPx5OvdXSApHUPbDAAGTrmAAQXg8EkMS8pAgu-3MUHvcJbsledl8sVMFXXiMmLx8M9rfbne7vf7UDfV4Qj69aLsuF5rpuNIxBGIDLquyBICg2Crn%202DXtWPpQtAMAKPykgmDyABK-aduQAA8oqCg6s4TmAnooJg1RAXmHaIHiWGwOgngxA6jj4bUj7Lj2fYUl4BBfKQBAQOBMBco%20v4UleXq3j6uEJCY6C0gySRMuqeLcYSAkoJ%20ECsT%20In-nxJhVre9a3n6AY4XhJjMdKIG%20veSqrhCIFYSAJjeCYIACnieKwgQV5AA), that was a fun problem.

```js
const str = `[{"user_id":"561904e8-6e45-5012-a9d8-e2ff8761acf6","email_addr":"jilov@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]},{"user_id":"5904003b-452b-535c-9615-94706bf6c66c","email_addr":"sawu@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]}]`;
const obj = JSON.parse(str);

function toCamelCase(snake_case) {
  return snake_case.replace(/([-_][a-z])/ig, ($1) => {
    return $1.toUpperCase()
      .replace('-', '')
      .replace('_', '');
  });
}

function transformObject(obj) {
  if (obj && Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(e => transformObject(e));
  }
  if (obj && typeof obj === "object") {
    const final = {};
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      final[toCamelCase(key)] = transformObject(val);
    }
    return final;
  }
  return obj;
}
const transformed = transformObject(obj);
console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: Care to add the example to the question so that this is not a "link only" answer?

Comment: Yep, I'm working on it. The answer's looking pretty sad for now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I think should work:

```js
const str = `[{"user_id":"561904e8-6e45-5012-a9d8-e2ff8761acf6","email_addr":"jilov@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]},{"user_id":"5904003b-452b-535c-9615-94706bf6c66c","email_addr":"sawu@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]}]`;
let obj = JSON.parse(str);


function snakeToCamel(str) {
    const splitString = str.split('_');
    let result = "";
    splitString.forEach((sstr, iter) => {
        if (iter !== 0) {
            result += sstr.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sstr.slice(1);
        } else
            result += sstr;

    })
    return result;
}

function convertToCamelCase(target) {
    const keys = Object.keys(target);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        if (typeof target[key] === 'object')
            convertToCamelCase(target[key]);

        const converted = snakeToCamel(key);
        if (key !== converted) {
            target[converted] = target[key];
            delete target[key];
        }
    });
}

convertToCamelCase(obj)
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Array.reduce()` function with a recursive camelCase modifier function will do the trick. This is scalable and works for deeply nested variables as well

```js
const str = `[{"user_id":"561904e8-6e45-5012-a9d8-e2ff8761acf6","email_addr":"jilov@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]},{"user_id":"5904003b-452b-535c-9615-94706bf6c66c","email_addr":"sawu@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]}]`;

const getCamelCaseFrom = (a) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).map(s => {
    if (Array.isArray(s[1])) s[1] = s[1].map(x => getCamelCaseFrom(x));
    s[0] = s[0].split('_').map((e, i) => i === 0 ? e : e.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1)).join('');
    return s
  }))
}
let json = JSON.parse(str).reduce((b, a) => ([...b, getCamelCaseFrom(a)]), [])

console.log(json)
```

Comment: I don't know if the code as it is now can be properly used, as `str` could very well be a JSON object, not an array

Comment: this is the OP's data and it is a JSON object, not sure what you mean

Comment: The answer's completely fine for that input data, what I meant was it wouldn't work on something that isn't an array

Answer (score 0):

With no regex and by simple reducing you may perhaps do like;

```js
function snake2camel(str){
  var b = false;
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call( str
                                    , (r,c) => c === "_" ? ( b = true
                                                           , r
                                                           )
                                                         : r += (b ? ( b = false
                                                                     , c.toUpperCase()
                                                                     )
                                                                   : c)
                                    , ""
                                    );
}
var str = `[{"user_id":"561904e8-6e45-5012-a9d8-e2ff8761acf6","email_addr":"jilov@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]},{"user_id":"5904003b-452b-535c-9615-94706bf6c66c","email_addr":"sawu@fake.com","details":[{"city_name":"fake city","country_name":"fake country"}]}]`;

console.log(JSON.parse(snake2camel(str)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: that's some interesting indentation there